# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() HTML embedded

Tags: php, html, database

I have made a basic search engine and I try, to fetch the results, on the same page; moreover, the results have been retrieved and stored in the associative array, but the embedded code in HTML shows only one record, of the results. `

```
<?php
require('Configuration/config.php');
require('Configuration/db.php');



//If the user clicks, on the button search, the execute the query
if (isset($_POST['search_btn'])) {
    $search_query = $_POST['search'];
    //$search_query = htmlspecialchars($_POST['search']);
    //Create the query.
    $query = "SELECT * FROM The_primary_arkivum WHERE 
    Name = '$search_query' OR 
    Address = '$search_query' OR 
    Category = '$search_query' OR
    Country = '$search_query' OR
    State = '$search_query'";

    //Get the results.
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    //Fetch the data, of the result, to an array.
    $search_results = mysqli_fetch_all($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    //var_dump($search_results);
    //var_dump($search_query);

    //Free result
    mysqli_free_result($results);
    //Close the connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>

<?php include('included/header.php'); ?>
    <body>
        <div class = "header">
            <h2>Search</h2>
        </div>

        <form method="post" action="search_index.php">
            <div class="input-group">
              <label>Search</label>
              <input type="text" name="search" value="<?php echo $search; ?>">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn" name="search_btn">Search</button>
            </div>

            <?php foreach($search_results as $search_result) : ?>
            <div class="mySlides fade">
              <?php echo $search_result['Name']?>
              <?php echo $search_result['Address']?>
              <?php echo $search_result['Country']?>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </form>
<?php include('included/footer.php'); ?>
```

`

Comment: i am suspecting your foreach statment try `foreach($search_results as $search_result) {?>  <div class="mySlides fade"> .... <?php} ?>`

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Where is the vulnerability?

Comment: I have also made a blog system, with the same embedded PHP and its recursion is working.

Comment: I discovered that jQuery is creating the problem, but I am yet to discover how, as the code, which is executed from jQuery is isolated and commented.

Answer (score 0):

Your echo statements in your form do not have ending semicolons `;`. Try starting there.

```
<?php echo $search_result['Name'];?>
<?php echo $search_result['Address'];?>
<?php echo $search_result['Country'];?>
```

Comment: I also had a problem with my jQuery and my Java-Script. Thank you, I fixed everything.

Comment: @George that's good. Maybe you can show any future viewers your solution and mark this question as answered.

Comment: yes I have thought about it. I shall improvise timely, but the semi-colons  were not the solution to the problem, in fact they were irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: @George I wasn't referring to my answer, I was referring to yours. You can answer your own question and mark it as answered.

Comment: I just noticed that.